# CamJam LED HAT buttons do not latch

Tags: hardware

I'm using the CamJam Jam Hat, 6 LED, 2 Button, 1 Buzzer HAT.

Research found simple scripts which run and easily find Button presses.
Inserting the same code in a larger program and checking the same libraries are installed, the Buttons are not found & I believe this is related to the cycle time of the larger program versus the button switch timing.

Have checked using 'Text Editor Find', and there aren't any pin conflicts. Do I need a Daemon (background script) to catch & latch the Button presses? My program must not stall waiting for buttons. If so can anyone help with a source of info to create such a deamon. Other advice could be helpful.

Comment: We need to see a script which demonstrates the problem.  Details such as Pi model, programming language, and OS may also be useful.

Comment: this site is not for providing code ... it is for debugging your existing code

Comment: Thanks for responses. The program contains over 600 lines of comment and program.

Comment: I requested a "source of information"  as a guide to how to construct my own daemon. Tips & examples of other daemons would not go amiss.

Comment: @joan link to CanJam JamHat script that ran OK.                                         https://github.com/modmypi/jam-HAT/blob/master/buttons.py

Comment: @RogerMckee writing daemons is not Raspberry Pi specific ... do research in the Linux realm ... there are tutorials available

Comment: @jsotola Is a daemon the correct way to approach this problem. It may be too much at my level of expertise.   I will ask a new question with a code example.

Comment: do not post a new question... edit this one instead ... you have not described the problem ... all we know is that the button `states` are not persistent ... reduce your program to minimum code that still exhibits the problem and add it to your question

Comment: You will see that nobody actually gave a working answer. So, here's the solution to ALL NOOBS. Go to Google ChatGPT while it's still FREE. It gives working scripts and explains how they work and interreact. It answers ALL your questions with woking solutions. It does not try to get more goody points for itself by asking for scripts or correcting your punctuation etc.