# JamHat Button latching & timing

Tags: hardware

replacement question posted for clarity.

I am trying to use JamHat buttons to direct my Python 3 Robot program.
A typical code snippet demonstrates the problem. Run the snippet with the indicated sleep(0.5) delay functions OK. When the snippet is included in a larger Robot program it continuously fails to catch any button presses. Increasing the sleep(0.5) to 1.0 or greater demonstrates the longer loop problem.

````
 while loop == True:
    if (jh.button_1.is_pressed) or jh.button_2.is_pressed):
       print("8/1")
       if  (jh.button_2.is_pressed):
         print("button 2")
         jh.button_2.wait_for_release()
    elif  (jh.button_1.is_pressed):
         print("button 1")
         jh.button_1.wait_for_release()
         print("8/2")
    sleep(0.5) # represents program loop delay

    ```
````

Comment: Apologies for poor code format. I thought the ''' code ''' would format correctly. Pls kindly point to formating tutorials.

Comment: Press Edit.  In the top bar press ?

Comment: Use 'code sample' (curly brackets). I did that but you had already lost indentation, so you have to replace the code block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CamJam LED HAT buttons do not latch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/142889/camjam-led-hat-buttons-do-not-latch)

Comment: It may be poor format but it is also poor code. You are attempting to load incompatible and irrelevant libraries and omitted any diagnostics.

Comment: @Dirk haven't tried { } but correct char is `` not ''.  Logitech numeric KB prints 2x `` as shown.

Comment: @Milliways Script is not mine, should now eliminate your other points.

Comment: @joan Have checked for conflict between JamHat button pins & Robot motor pins & i2c pins. Believe timing is problem, anyone point to JamHat timing diagrams, schmatics or python script examples for long loop times, as indicated in the question.

Comment: @anybody No constructive suggestions so far. This script is a good example of the problem. Does anyone have a CamJam JamHat who can test this. Run script with sleep(0.5) fast loop, then with sleep(5) slow loop. Creating a daemon to catch Button Presses is taking too long. Any proposals please.